# octovis for ros-electric

Tags: slam, navigation, octomap, octovis, rgbd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to install octovis for ros-electric?

I tried $ sudo apt-get install ros-electric-octomap-visualization.
But it reported can't locate the package.

Then I read some of the discussions in ros.answers and tried from
$ svn co https://octomap.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/octomap/trunk octomap
and compiled using commands cmake and make

after that in the terminal I typed command $ ocotovis
It says command not found.

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance

Updated:
Also, while compiling I see the compilation is successful. I can see files inside folder build, bin and lib. Though, I am unable to open the octovis GUI. I used the above command to open that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39982/octovis-for-ros-electric/) by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2012-07-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-27**:
Did you check if it's build in a subdirectory like bin/?

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-07-29**:
Yes, it's built in the subdirectory. Though, it says command not found

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-29**:
So, did you execute the binary in bin/octovis or just type octovis?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-30**:
see answer.

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-07-30**:
yes, I got it. Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the file is in bin/octovis relative to your directory, execute bin/octovis.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3